# How to pass a DateTime from NodeJS Sequelize to MSSQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

I have a NodeJS project, and I am trying to pass an 'UpdateDate' field using Sequelize. I am receiving the error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'. I have tried passing a few different things:

```
Date.now()
new Date().toISOString()
```

Neither work. Am I missing something simple? I cannot change the column definition on the table. As far as I know, passing a string such as '2016-05-23 10:39:21.000' to a SQL DateTime field works in SSMS, but it seems to be an issue when using Sequelize and Node.

Thanks

Zach

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958525/datetime-conversion-failed-with-sequelise-inserting-a-sql-server-record

Comment: Thanks, that is related, and works. However, changing the column type may not be an option at this point. Do you know of another way without changing the SQL table definition? A way to pass a valid value from Javascript/Sequelize?

Comment: i dont know sequalize at all.. but based on what you are saying does `new Date().toISOString()` not produce a string like: `2017-11-01T14:50:33.239Z` i would try and format that as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime)

Answer (score 26):

This is caused by a [known issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7879) in Sequelize.  The solution is to patch Sequelize's date to string format implementation, like [explained here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7879#issuecomment-329971730), so that all dates are handled properly.  Below is the code that fixes the error.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Override timezone formatting for MSSQL
Sequelize.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  return this._applyTimezone(date, options).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
};
```

Comment: This works great, simply instantiate the override before calling `new Sequelize(...)`

Comment: I adapted this answer with sequelize 6.12.0-beta.1 (onward) with type script, you should use :
`DataTypes.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date: Date, options: any) {
    return this._applyTimezone(date, options).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
};`

Answer (score 9):

I figured this out, without changing the data type in the SQL database.

In my Model, I had my column defined as DataTypes.DATE, which, according to the Sequelize documentation, is the equivalent of a DateTime in SQL. However, this was throwing the error. When I changed the definition to DataTypes.STRING, and then added this:

```
var normalizedDate = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();
```

normalizedDate now passes through to the DateTime column in SQL without a problem. The issue that I can tell, is Sequelize was adding a time zone to the Date before passing it. Such as, a date like:

```
'2017-11-01 16:00:49.349'
```

was being passed through as:

```
'2017-11-01 16:00:49.349 +00:00'
```

and it looks like SQL server does not like the '+00:00'.

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this variable:

```
const timestamps = new Date() + 3600 * 1000 * 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I was able to solve the issue by changing the model as follows.
ex:

```
 create_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: new Date().toISOString(),
        allowNull: false
    },
    update_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue:new Date().toISOString(),
        allowNull: false
    }
```