# Sequelize How do you format date to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss and keep the columns as snake case

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, date, sequelize.js

Hi I am using Sequelize with a Postgres Database

So I am trying to format date on the sequelize createdAt and updatedAt columns as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` As well as keeping the columns as snake_case not camelcase so they would be `created_at` and `updated_at`How can I achieve this? I have tried the following:

```
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      field: 'created_at'
    },
```

or

```
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.NOW,
      set(value) {
        return value.toISOString().replace(/\..+/g, '')
// coming in the db as 2021-10-31 01:34:48.81+00 so wanted to remove evrything after the dot
      },
      name: 'createdAt',
      field: 'created_at',
    },
```

Is not working and I am getting this error

```
          throw new Error(`Value for "${key}" option must be a string or a boolean, got ${typeof this.options[key]}`);
          ^

Error: Value for "createdAt" option must be a string or a boolean, got object
```

Here is the whole table defined above is what I have pinpointed which I need help with

```
  const Supplier = sequelize.define('Supplier', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 50]
      }
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'suppliers',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.NOW,
      set(value) {
        return value.toISOString().replace(/\..+/g, '')
      },
      name: 'createdAt',
      field: 'created_at',
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.NOW,
      set(value) {
        return value.toISOString().replace(/\..+/g, '')
      },
      field: 'updated_at',
    },
    // freezeTableName: true
    // paranoid: true
  });
```

Thanks

Today Sequelize docs is not working here is a webarchive's for it

https://web.archive.org/web/20200731154157/http://sequelize.org/master/index.html

Comment: The error says createdAt expects a string or a bool, and the code looks like it assigns an object `createdAt: {...}`

Comment: How can I be specific in making it a string and formatted as ``YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`` and keeping the column as snake case.

I know for instance if I did:

``createdAt: 'created_at',`` 

as stated on their docs I am making the column as snake case so my other goal I have is formatting it as I have stated without the milliseconds in the DB so how can I do that? @danh

Comment: I just did some edits in the "get()" method for getting the exact format as you want, so it's ready now. Also it would be nice if you'll add the "postgres" tag under your question as well as the "date" type is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

As for above the `get()` method will only return the value as formatted to the client but **it wont save it to the database.** I have found three options to make it save to the database thus the solution for this issue for anyone experiencing something similar.

**1. First Option**

Inside the **node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js**

We have to modify the following code

```
DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  date = this._applyTimezone(date, options);

  // Z here means current timezone, _not_ UTC
  // return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z');// from this to the below code
  return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'); // to this
};
```

**2. Second Option**

If you don't to touch your node_modules folder and do not like option 1, than a somewhat better solution would be to do what you did at option 1 but in your own db.js file:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { DB } = require('../config');

// Override timezone formatting by requiring the Sequelize and doing it here instead
Sequelize.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  date = this._applyTimezone(date, options);

  // Z here means current timezone, _not_ UTC
  // return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z');
  return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
};

const db = new Sequelize(`${DB.DIALECT}://${DB.USER}:${DB.PASS}@${DB.HOST}:${DB.PORT}/${DB.DB}`, {
  logging: false
})

module.exports = db;
```

So this two option is more like global way off doing it so the format will be for all your models.

**3. Third Option**

Final option is to do it for each single models by using hooks

Example:

```
const Supplier = sequelize.define('Supplier', {
// col attributes 
}, {
    tableName: 'suppliers',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    hooks : {
      beforeCreate : (record, options) => {
          record.dataValues.created_at = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/g, '');
          record.dataValues.updated_at = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/g, '');
      },
      beforeUpdate : (record, options) => {
          record.dataValues.updated_at = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/g, '');
      }
    },
})
```

Comment: My yhoughts: I can't say anything good or bad about this, but it would be nice if you'll know how these solutions could affect on your app future-development/performance. P.S. the choice is yours anyway ;)

Comment: 1. if you want to have changes in core package, you don't have to change anything in node_modules (you know how badly is this)

Comment: 2. if you make changes in "DATE.prototype._stringify" you must know that it will affect on your whole app and you can't use DATE type as before in the future (the same for 1-st), if this not a problem for you, then this maight be useful for you.

Comment: 3. keep in mind that sequelize "hooks" will work little bit slowly, cuz you've used regex-replace (regex-actions not recommended, but only for critical cases, so try to avoid them), and "beforeCreate"/"beforeUpdate" will work on each saving/editing DB request and will somehow slowdown that process as well.

Comment: Thanks for your question, I've explored much stuff as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question contains some subquetions:

- Sequelize table column underscored names;
- Sequelize date format;
- Usage without [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment);

Here's some working example (with requirements mentioned above) I've just got:

**Have a sequelize migration like this:**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('items', {
            // ...
            created_at: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            // ...
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('items');
    }
};
```

**Have a sequelize model like this:**

```
'use strict';

// WITH moment
// const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    // const now = new Date();
    return sequelize.define('Item', {
        // ...
        created_at: {
            allowNull: false,
            // defaultValue: now,
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            get() {
                // 1. WITHOUT moment
                const date = new Date(`${this.dataValues.created_at}`);
                return `${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]} ${date.toLocaleTimeString([], {month: '2-digit', timeStyle: 'medium', hour12: false})}`;
                
                // 2. WITHOUT moment (another solution)
                // const parts = date.toISOString().split('T');
                // return `${parts[0]} ${parts[1].substring(0, 8)}`;
                
                // 3. WITH moment
                // return moment(this.dataValues.created_at).format('D MM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // 'D MMM YYYY, LT'
            }
        },
        // ...
    }, {
        tableName: 'items',
        freezeTableName: true,
        // underscored: true,
        timestamps: false,
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    });
};
```

Don't forget to rename your table name for your needs, here is "items".

Seems there is an [issue posted on github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10857) with sequelize "underscored" property. Anyway it worked for me, cuz there is a small trick with other properties, so just do like that and I believe it should work (Sequelize version for me was "^5.22.3").

Sources I've used:

- [date formatting with/without Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094020/7574023)
- [JavaScript Date toLocaleString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp)
- [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803/7574023)
- [Javascript add leading zeroes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160545/7574023)
- [How do I use .toLocaleTimeString() without displaying seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333267/7574023)

Feel free to edit and optimize if you need (I did some small edits in the get() method for getting the exact format as you want, anyway I prefer to use moment as a column accessor).

Comment: Thanks but still the get() method just enables you to see the date as formatted ``YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`` but it is not saved with this format to the database itself. As it says on the sequelize doc that the get method only shows you on the console but wont save it to the database. So I want to save the format as you done to the Database I am trying to use the set method but  I am not having any luck in it

https://web.archive.org/web/20200730080051/http://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html

Comment: Seems, [it's a known issue in Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49678951/7574023). You have two solutions for that 1. actually you don't need to keep the date in column with "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format, it will add the part to the right anyway (you can just use by-default or custom getters for that, and it will not appear anywhere in your app, it only just keeps like that); 2. Or if you want that anyway you can use some additional tricks like [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3892#issuecomment-111769712)

Comment: for example in my app I've used these 2 types (DATEONLY and DATE) like [this](https://imgur.com/a/YYMR6jX), and it didn't prevented me to do formatting as I want

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. I have now taken my time to look into those links you sent me. I like this solution
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7879 ,, By the user: dlredden from 16 sep 2017.. Sequelize should have sorted this issue long time ago, instead of making us change something from the node_modules file. But  the solution by user dlredden on the github issue link is pretty cool. We are not directly touching the node_modules but requiring from it and applying our own modification.

Comment: I found another solution is by using hooks like this https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13613